# Software for scanning installation process?

Tags: windows, installation, automation

I forgot what is the name of the very good software which make some kind of restore point (save registry, and program files folder, etc...) before installing any software. After you install some program (ie "Notepad++") you can easily see what registry data use new installed program, on what location are the file's is stored and many more. The reason that I'm asking for help is that I have to automate some installation of public software, so after installation I need to uninstall it, so i have to delete all junk files. The software is called something like install wizard, or wizard install I forgot. If you have any idea of other application that do same thing , or you know exactly name of that software, or you have some good idea how to solve easy solve many installation and uninstallation, please let me know.

Os: win7/xp 64/32

Comment: The program is called InstallWatch pro 2.5 and can be downloaded from http://www.softsea.com/review/InstallWatch.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've used InstallRite to create [FOG snapins](http://fogproject.org/wiki/index.php?title=Managing_FOG#Creating_a_Snapin_.2F_Overview); the homepage is down at the moment but a Google search should find you some download links. It allows you to capture the state of the filesystem and registry for later comparison, mainly after a software install but you can also capture things like registry keys for settings changes.

Alternatively, you can try [SFX Maker](http://www.isoft-online.com/) which has some good recommendations but I've not used it myself.

Comment: thnx man you help me .. :) I can't vote up because low reputation, but when i become bigger shore will :)